# MySQL schema name with dash does not allow me to execute command line query

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, vagrant

I have create a shell script to automate my database migration from host to host, that extracts my Multi WordPress site tables into separated `sql` files, so I can decide what site I will migrate each time.

So in my shell script I have the following code:

```
schema="internet-safe"
PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME="internet-safe"
vagrant_export_folder="/var/www/projects/${PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME}/database/tmp"

query="mysql -uroot -proot -e \"SELECT blog_id AS ID, path AS Slug FROM ${schema}.wp_blogs "
query="$query INTO OUTFILE '$vagrant_export_folder/blogs.csv' "
query="$query FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
query="$query ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' "
query="$query LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' \" > /dev/null"

vagrant ssh --command "cd $vagrant_export_folder && $query"
```

But by executing this script I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-safe.wp_blogs  INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/projects/internet-safe/database/tmp/blogs' at line 1
```

Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

An the problem is the dash in the schema name `internet-safe`. Is there a way to correct this issue ?

I know that there is an option, to just rename the schema, but, unfortunately I run on unstable vagrant, on xUbuntu, that has destroy my database several times, while I try to provision modifications in my databases.

I also have try the following combinations but I get error messages like the following:

```
`${schema}`.`wp_blogs`


ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/projects/internet-safe/database/tmp/blogs.csv'  FIELDS TE' at line 1


`${schema}`.wp_blogs


ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected



`${schema}.wp_blogs`


ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/projects/internet-safe/database/tmp/blogs.csv'  FIELDS TE' at line 1
```

Comment: Add a ` ` to wrap the schema name

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Not possible in shell script. See my answer.

Comment: escaping the backticks worked for me:
--execute="DROP DATABASE \`router-xxxxxx\`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be of course to simply rename your database.

Usually when special characters appear in schema/table/column names, you can fix this with backticks. Since you're trying to run a shell script, it will interpret anything within backticks as a command, unfortunately.

In MySQL you can set the sql_mode "ANSI_QUOTES". Do so as administrator/root (in MySQL) with

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode="ANSI_QUOTES";
```

Check first, if you have any modes set already with

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

If there are already modes set, include those in the `SET GLOBAL sql_mode` statement (separated by `,`).

You can also set this option in your `my.cnf` file, so that this mode is applied every time you start your MySQL server.

The effect is, that `"` is also allowed as identifier quote character. But be careful, that you don't use `"` in queries to specify any text, use single-quotes there instead.

- read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)